# IE favicon disappeared when navigating other page in angular application

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, google-chrome, favicon, angularjs-routing

I found an issue with angular application.
I have a the location provider setup to use the html5Mode true:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

I noticed that the favicon is disappearing when navigating between pages.
I'm using IE11 edge document mode.

Does anyone bumped into this too?

Thanks

Comment: Happens in Chrome as well, looks like a known bug with push state: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=50298.

Comment: Hi @Bill, I have a different results than those you described. First of all it's not happens on Chrome, then after reading the posts in the link you provided I found its more related to an anchor tag inside a page for a specific place in the same page - plus it appears to happen only in Mac. One last thing i found out that this is happens also in other website such as FB - the favicon disappears after navigating different pages.

Comment: If it happens on Facebook too, are the AngularJS tags relevant?

Comment: I am guessing here but try  favicon.ico?def=abcdefghijklmn so it would not cache it?

Answer (score 1):

Thought it might be worth adding my findings here...

At first I had the exact same problem, I couldn't get the favicon to stay on the page when changing from the root home page. I tried Shaun's answer and that didn't work either so I looked online a bit more and found that in all modern browsers you are able to use PNGs as your default favicon so I tried that and it worked for me in latest Chrome, latest Firefox and IE11 via localhost and then in Edge once I published to my webserver.

I hope this helps anyone else out that was having the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will work for you or not.

This code assumes you have `jQuery` as well as `angularjs` (not just `jqlite`). An equivalent in pure javascript would be possible (though longer).

```
angular.module('app', [])
.run(function ($rootScope, $location) {

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

    // bug fix: reset favicon path
    var favType = "image/x-icon"
    favLink = $('link[type="' + favType + '"]').remove().attr("href");
    $('<link href="' + favLink + '" rel="shortcut icon" type="' + favType + '" />').appendTo('head');

  })

});
```