# favicon disappeared when navigating other page in IE

Tags: html, angularjs, internet-explorer, web-hosting, favicon

I know it is a duplicate question. But there is no solution about it.
IE favicon disappeared when navigating other page in angular application

When in angularjs I navigate with the following code. browser lost favicon.ico from tab and URL Bar.

```
$location.path();
```

Site is hosted in same domain but two project separately published.
I am accessing the icon from project1 to project2 on the home page but not after that it is visible.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982726/ie-favicon-disappeared-when-navigating-other-page-in-angular-application/33685080#33685080

Comment: Just added an answer there that may help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IE favicon disappeared when navigating other page in angular application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982726/ie-favicon-disappeared-when-navigating-other-page-in-angular-application)